# Access Class Constants Dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, constants, class-constants

I want to be able to look up the value of a constant dynamically, but using a variable doesn't work with the syntax.

```
<?php
class Food {
    const FRUITS = 'apple, banana, orange';
    const VEGETABLES = 'spinach, carrot, celery';
}

$type = 'FRUITS';

echo Food::FRUITS;
echo Food::$type;

?>
```

gives

```
apple, banana, orange

Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Food::$type
```

How can I dynamically call the constant?

Comment: I suppose you can't.

Answer (score 9):

The only solution which comes to my head is using a [`constant` function](https://www.php.net/constant):

```
echo constant('Food::' . $type);
```

Here you create name of a constant, including class, as a string and pass this string (`'Food::FRUITS'`) to `constant` function.

Comment: Yeah.  Using a ReflectionClass to get an array of all of the constants is another way of programmatically looking up the value.  I was hoping there was some obscure syntax to grab the value with a single statement/action.

Answer (score 2):

This will be available natively in php8.3 as of November 2023

```
class MyClass {
    public const MY_CONST = 42;
}

$constName = 'MY_CONST';

echo MyClass::{$constName};
```

https://php.watch/versions/8.3/dynamic-class-const-enum-member-syntax-support

Comment: Please post a descriptive answer and then references.

Answer (score 0):

A ReflectionClass can be used to get an array of all of the constants, and then the value of the specific constant can be found from there:

```
<?php
class Food {
    const FRUITS = 'apple, banana, orange';
    const VEGETABLES = 'spinach, carrot, celery';
}

$type = 'FRUITS';

$refClass = new ReflectionClass('Food');
$constants = $refClass->getConstants();

echo $constants[$type];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using namespaces, make sure you include the namespace, even if it's autoloaded.

````
namespace YourNamespace;

class YourClass {
  public const HELLO = 'WORLD'; 
}

$yourConstant = 'HELLO';

// Not working
// >> PHP Warning:  constant(): Couldn't find constant YourClass::HELLO ..
constant('YourClass::' . $yourConstant);

// Working
constant('YourNamespace\YourClass::' . $yourConstant);```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can create associative array

```
class Constants{
  const Food = [
      "FRUITS " => 'apple, banana, orange',
      "VEGETABLES" => 'spinach, carrot, celery'
  ];
}
```

and access value like this

```
$type = "FRUITS";

echo Constants::Food[$type];
```